# dotted border is displayed incorrectly in safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I have the problem that in Safari the border is wrongly displayed.
Are there any CSS settings to consider? Or is something missing?? Thank You.

This is the CSS:

```
.border-dotted {
border-width: 0px 0px 7px 0px;
border-style: dotted;
border-color: black;
border-image-source: url(/img/dot.svg);
border-image-slice: 36% 38%;
border-image-repeat: round;
}
```

This is how it is displayed in Safari: [image]

This is how it is displayed in Chrome: [image]

Comment: I am not sure but try `-webkit-` property may be it's work.

Comment: This is more likely a problem of your `dot.svg`. Can you attach the svg code?

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure it is work or not in safari but you can try.

```
.border-dotted{
border: 7px dotted black;
}
```

you can change it which way you want like border-bottom.